# default react route conflicts with route with params

Tags: reactjs, react-router

my app.js code

```
<Switch>
          <Route exact path='/' component={HomePage} />
          <Route exact path='/about' component={About} />
          <Route exact path='/careers' component={Careers} />
          <Route
            exact
            path='/solutions/standard'
            render={() => <Solutions solution='Standard' />}
          />
          <Route
            exact
            path='/solutions/custom'
            render={() => <Solutions solution='Custom' />}
          />
          <Route component={NotFound} />
          <Route
            exact
            path='/detail/:solution/:prod'
            component={Detail}
          ></Route>
          />
        </Switch>
```

but when i go to /detail/something/something it renders the default 'not found' component instead of rendering the 'detail' component and sending 'solution' and 'prod' as params

also, for the Solution component, instead of having the same component just with different props how can i specify the option of a param, for example:

```
<Route exact path='/solutions/:standard || custom' component={Solution} />
```

Comment: Have you tried that `Route` without `exact`?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky yes

Comment: Move `<Route component={NotFound} />` below all over routes

Comment: It works if you move it below everything else: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-v5w7tu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For solutions, you can do something like this

```
  <Route path='/solutions/:path(custom|standard)' component={Solutions} />
```

This ensures that the route will only render when the path parameter is `custom` or `standard`.

You could also exclude `(custom|standard)` if you want to match other parameters, like this...

```
  <Route path='/solutions/:path' component={Solutions} />
```

For the detail route issue, move the all-route matcher `<Route component={NotFound} />` to the last position in the `<Switch>`. This will ensure that all other routes will try to match before returning the `NotFound` component.

```
  <Switch>
    // All other routes
    <Route component={NotFound} />
  </Switch>
```

Comment: what does 'path' stand for when you say `<Route path='/solutions/:path(custom|standard)' component={Solutions} />`?

Comment: `:path` is the url parameter for that route. It can be named anything. You could name it `:solution` so it's more meaningful to you. `<Route path="/solutions/:solution" component={Solutions} />`

Comment: what is in the parenthesis, is it regex, javascript or somthing else?

Comment: Yes, it is regex. More on that here https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp

Comment: @ladiasenusi, is this something that i need to install or its within the react core?

Comment: You don't need to install it or bother about it. React router already has it under the hood